# how to count no of left or right child from binary tree database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

This is a dummy of my table

[image: table]

- first node is 1
- LorR define child is ini left(0) or Right(1)
- 1 st node has two child node 2 and 3 in Left and Right
- 2 nd node has two child node 4 and 5 in Left and Right
- 3 rd node has two child node 6 and 7 in Left and Right
- 4 th node has two child node 8 and 9 in Left and Right
- 5 th node has one child node 10 in Left
- 6 th node has one child node 11 in Left
- 7 th node has one child node 12 in Right

now if i want to find the number of total child nodes of any parent node in each level
for ex...

- node 2 (parent) has a 2 child (4,5) in level 1 & 2 child node (8,9)
  in level 2
- node 6 (parent) has a 1 child (11) in level 1
- node 3 (parent) has a 2 child (6,7) in level 1 & 2 child nodes
  (11,12) in level 2

how can I implement this using php? 
My code is 
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkW5c.png)

Comment: Could you please post the code for your best attempt. Thanks.

Comment: the code which i worked out is given below

Comment: Shouldn't node 2 (parent) have 2 child (4,5) in level 1, and 3 (not 2) child in level 2 (8, 9, 10)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I am understanding, you should transform the table into informative PHP array, something like:

```
$a = array(
    1 => array(
        'children' => array(
            array(2, 'left'),
            array(3, 'right'),
        ),
        'level' => 0
    ),
    2 => array(
        'children' => array(
            array(4, 'left'),
            array(5, 'right'),
        ),
        'level' => 1
    ),
...        
    12 => array(
        'children' => array(),
        'level' => 3
    ),
);
```

This task is quite easy, just fetch the table then foreach and assign each row into associated array.
Here is the function to get all children count:

```
function getChildrenCount($nodeId, $a, $rootLevel)
{
    $leftChildren = array();
    $rightChildren = array();
    $countCurrentNode = 0;
    $level = $a[$nodeId]['level'] - $rootLevel;
    if (empty($a[$nodeId]['children'])) {
        return array($level => 1);
    } else {
        foreach ($a[$nodeId]['children'] as $children) {
            if ($children[1] == 'left') {
                $leftChildren = getChildrenCount($children[0], $a, $rootLevel);
                $countCurrentNode++;
            }
            if ($children[1] == 'right') {
                $rightChildren = getChildrenCount($children[0], $a, $rootLevel);
                $countCurrentNode++;
            }
        }

        $current = $leftChildren;
        foreach ($rightChildren as $rightLevel => $count) {
            if (isset($current[$rightLevel])) {
                $current[$rightLevel] += $count;
            } else {
                $current[$rightLevel] = $count;
            }
        }
        $current[$level] = $countCurrentNode;
        return $current;
    }
}
```

The idea is the recursive traversal each node, then calculate number of children based on its level (compared with root level)

How to call:

```
getChildrenCount(2, $a, $a[2]['level'])
```

It will return array(level => count):

```
array (size=3)
0 => int 2 // level 1
1 => int 3 // level 2
2 => int 3 // Should be removed
```

Then you should remove the last element - it's useless as it's used to count child by level.

Note:

1. It should have a better way to organize the data (array $a), to have easier getChildrenCount() implementation.
2. This code is not tested carefully, just checked with some cases.

Comment: I guess this is what i am looking for.But can you explain more about the associative array generation.?Is this the query you are mentioning?   'SELECT * FROM table WHERE Parent node=2 '

Comment: If your table is not too big, you can fetch all "SELECT * FROM table", then foreach one by one to create associated array (it needs 2 foreach I guess). If your table is too big, you need to have a recursive function to get parent-and-children row : SELECT * FROM table WHERE ParentNode = 2, then fetch the result and SELECT * FROM table WHER ParentNode = {fetchedId}...

Comment: thankyou so much...code worked with some alterations:)